Next.js and valtio : TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'validated' of object '#<Object>'
I use valtio in Next.js 14 project.
index.ts
export const state = proxy({title:'Hello', content:null})

And I store component in state.content.
When I see state, It's like {title:'Hello', content:content}
I want to render component like this,
const Page = () => {
  const snapshot = useProxy(state);

  return (
    <div>{snapshot.content}</div>
  )
}

And I have an error like this

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'validated' of object '#'

Could I know how to fix this error and how to store component in valtio, call and show in another component??
